# Swiftui List animation

Tags: ios, listview, animation, swiftui

I am trying to animate the contents of a list of points. The list is sorted from highest to lowest, so it reorganizes as lower values are higher than the row above. The animation works great by using `.animation(.default)` on the list, however, it also animates the entire list when I open the view. The whole list floats into place. I would the list to be static, and just the rows move when necessary to reorder

```swift
List {
    ForEach(players) { player in
        Text(player.score)
    }
}.animation(.default)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To animate only when something in the `State` data changes, use a `withAnimation` surrounding the part where you change it rather than the whole list:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Player: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var score: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var players: [Player] = [
        .init(score: "2"),
        .init(score: "3"),
        .init(score: "6"),
        .init(score: "1")]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("shuffle") {
                withAnimation(.easeIn) {
                    players.shuffle()
                }
            }
            List {
                ForEach(players) { player in
                Text(player.score)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you change the List animation type tho? In UITable you can choose different animation types, like opacity, slide in, slide down, etc